# Better way to create text based game

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right, i was uncertain if I should post this as it is a little *vague* but I really would like some help with this so I will try explain as best as possible.

### The Idea:

To create a text based game using Javascript/jQuery, the game will be that of one where a story is being told and you get to pick the options.

My idea was to use a `textarea` to allow input from the user (select a option) and output text (from the story).

### How far have I got?

Well this is what I have created so far.

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

```
var current, text, location, option1, option2;
location = ''; // house, car, moon
current = 0;
gameOver = false;
pick = false;

jQuery("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var content = this.value;
        var lastLine = content.substr(content.lastIndexOf("\n") + 1);

        // Story
        if (current == 0 && pick == false) {
            option1 = 'Look around';
            option2 = 'Check you have arms (Check arms)';
            text = 'You open your eyes \n\nOptions: \n' + option1 + '\n' + option2;
            pick = true;

        } else if (current == 0 && lastLine == 'Check arms' && pick == true) {
            text = 'You check your arms, they seem fine';
            pick = false;
        } else if (current == 0 && lastLine == 'Look around' && pick == true || current == 2 && lastLine == 'Get Out') {
            option1 = 'Walk to a nearby house';
            option2 = 'Get in a rocket that is next to you (Get in rocket)';
            text = 'You do a 360 spin, you see you have limited options \n\nOptions: \n' + option1 + '\n' + option2;
            pick = false;
            if (current == 2 && lastLine == 'Get Out') {
                current = 1;
            } else {
                current++;
            }
        }

        //House Story
        else if (current == 1 && lastLine == 'Walk to house' && pick == false) {
            option1 = 'Knock on the front door';
            option2 = 'Jump through the front window';
            text = 'You walk to the house and see there are no lights on, the building is old and appears to be burnt out\n\nOptions: \n ' + option1 + '\n ' + option2;
            pick = false;
            current++;
        }

        // Rocket story
        else if (current == 1 && lastLine == 'Get in rocket' && pick == false) {
            option1 = 'Get out of the rocket(Get out)';
            option2 = 'Hit the biggest button you can find(Hit Button)';
            text = 'You hop into the rocket, there are a lot of buttons infront of you\n\nOptions: \n ' + option1 + '\n ' + option2;
            pick = false;
            current++;
        }

        $('textarea ').val($('textarea ').val() + '\n\n ' + text + '\n ');
    }
});
```

It works (kinda) but it is getting complicated to code like this. To me its very messy and I have tried to re-write it but I cannot find a way to make this neat/ easier to code.

### Have a look at the demo:

Please do take a look at the demo if you wish to try and help me as you will get a good idea what I am trying to achieve.

**Demo walk-through:**

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/B3Ack/6/)

1. In the `textarea` click enter to start
2. Type one of the options to progress in the game (Options: Check arms or Look around)
3. Type one of the options to progress in the game (Options: Walk to a nearby house or Get in rocket)
4. End of demo

*Note: After typing a option click enter to continue. At the moment all options must be typed exactly as seen (If option has brackets you type that instead)*

This is a short demo but you should get the point. I have searched around and cant find/think of a suitable method to code this game.

### Get to the point, what's the question?

My questions is: What **is** a suitable method to code this game?

Suitable: Easy to maintain/read + add new story "parts" etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with some kind of strategy pattern. Create i.e. a Game constructor

```
var Game = new function(strategy) {
    this.strategy = strategy;
}

Game.prototyp.playScene = function() {
    return this.strategy();
}
```

Then you can create `scenes` where you would place your logic

```
var sceneOne = function() {
    console.log('First scene logic here');
}

var sceneTwo = function() {
    console.log('Second scene logic here');
}
```

and finally you can call these logics as follows:

```
var game;
if(e.which == 13) {
    if(condition1) {
        game = new Game(sceneOne);
    } else {
        game = new Game(sceneTwo);
    } 

    game.playScene();
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9tSZ/1/)

Comment: Very nice! I shall attempt this method, not fully managed to wrap my head around it yet. If there's any chance you could create a demo that would be great and extremely helpful (I tend to understand things better seeing them work). If not now worries I'm sure I can get the hang of it by messing around. +1 I like it, thank you!

Comment: I've provided a simple example in a fiddle

Comment: @Ruddy Too bad the question was closed. This is something close to my heart. You might learn a lot by looking at the source code for "a dark room". It's a really pretty Javascript text game.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue I see here is that your code is going to grow and grow as your game/story expands. You're actually writing the logic of your game in the code itself.

As an alternative I would suggest splitting out your logic into steps and logic. For example:

```
var allTiles = 
[
  {location: 'Forest', description: 'Deep, dark and scary'},
  {location: 'Castle', description: 'High, made from stone and very dramatic'},
];

var currentState = 
{
  equipment: ['Sword', 'Bow', '3 gold coins'];
  currentLocationIndex: 0
};
```

These may of course be in different files so you can add locations to your world.

Next you need your core logic class, this will look a lot like the one you've already got:

```
jQuery("textarea").keypress(function (e) {
    var currentLocation = allTiles[currentState.currentLocationIndex];
    printDescription(currentLocation.Description);


   // process commands... into pseudo code territory
   if(userDoesAction1){
     currentLocation.doAction1();
   }
}
```

I've not gone into massive detail here - it will depend very much on the structure of your game. Personally I like the idea of creating an array functions in your location which are things you can do at your location... actually, JS is a very nice language to do this sort of game!

Comment: Interesting! And it looks very neat using arrays, I think I will have ago at this method when I get a chance. I know this is asking a lot but if you have a chance could you create a quick demo? Would be great to see it working so I can get a feel for how easy it would be using this method. Thank you for your answer +1 from me!

Comment: I may struggle to add a lot more to it any time soon - Dieter Goetelen's answer has captured my idea for adding actions into the locations very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [jQuery terminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl). Then you can write core of the game that act on data in JSON object. If you write something like this you will be able to change the data (update or replace) without need to change the code, it's called data driven programming (Eric Raymond write nice [chapter in his book about it](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch09s01.html))

Comment: Hmm, I will have to read up on this. I will have to have a look into this jQuery terminal a bit more when I get a chance. Thank you for your answer +1 as could be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

When making games i think that an Object Oriented approach is the best to keep things separated and easy to code and find:

For example you could separate the different rooms in your game in different function structures.

```
var parentFunction = function(){

  var protectedValue = ‘variable’;

  var childFunction = function(){

    alert(protectedValue);

  }

  childFunction();

}
var object = new parentFunction();
```

You initialize the function every time you move to the related ambient, and put the possible actions that the player can take in child-functions.
But i guess the answer would be too big here: you should spend some time before starting to make a scheme of the logic that your game will follow and how you want to separate things (and how they relate to each other).